# Function to return results in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm writing a calculator, in Python, to calculate all 4 operations, (Add, Sub, Mul, and Div); I need to create a function that would return results of the 4 operations in a dictionary: result = all(n1,n2), for example all(4,2); this is to return something like this: result["add":6, "sub":2, "mul":8, "div": 2]; to print as: 4 + 2 = 6, 4 - 2 = 2, 4 * 2 = 8, 4 / 2 = 2
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem :-) Go ahead and get started on it, and let us know if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you want a "dictionary". Dictionaries can only have 1 key and 1 definition. However if you use pandas and a data-frame you can store all of these.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_dataframe.htm